# Console error: [function] is not defined, although it is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, function-call

I'm calling my function in my HTML, and even though the function originates in the same file I'm receiving an error stating that the function is undefined. I cleared the browser cache, but with no luck.

I tried calling the function in a click event in the same `<script>`, but the click event wasn't recognized at all:

```
$("#addFileButton").on("click", function() {
  uploadFile();
  console.log("click")
})
```

---

This is what my code looks like now:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input id="getFile" type="file" multiple="multiple"/><br />
<input id="addFileButton" type="button" value="upload" onclick="uploadFile();" />
<!-- etc -->
</div>

<script>
  function uploadFile() {
    // code
  }
</script>
```

---

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Tsardines/Lrcgfjhq/5/

Comment: You are missing either `#` in `$("addFileButton")`

Comment: why you define two  Onlick events

Comment: @Rkv88-Kanyan It's just what I tried (jQuery onClick, not working) and what I'm trying now (HTML inline onclick, not working either). I never have both of them at the same time.

Comment: If JS says the function is not defined, then it is not defined. Was the script containing the function really loaded? If there's a syntax error in the function, that makes it also undefined.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I added it back to the example, thanks. The jQuery click event still isn't working, though.

Comment: Order of the script tags matter; try to move `uploadFile` function declaration to the top of scripts;

Comment: your problem is that you put script tag after html body

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A that would not cause the reported problem.

Comment: @Rkv88-Kanyan Are you guessing or do you somehow know what he's html looks like?

Comment: @Rkv88-Kanyan no, that's fine. Also you cannot tell whether that's what the OP did from the code posted.

Comment: Or is the error message about `$` ..? I.e. jQuery isn't loaded.

Comment: hi  can you post full html to help  if your problem still exists

Comment: @Teemu Nope :( I moved `$("#addFileButton")` to my `index.js` file (where other click events are), and I'm getting the "function undefined" error again.

Comment: It is a waste of everyone's time to keep guessing. How about you show how the code is actually laid out in the files and how the files reference each other. A [mre], if you will. For instance, when I put this code into jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ye3a6qk/ it works.

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the exact error message?

Comment: @HereticMonkey & Teemu: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/Tsardines/Lrcgfjhq/3/ I included the error message as well

Comment: @Bodrov Please incorporate the required information into the question here on Stack Overflow, not an external link.

Comment: Umh .. the function name in the fiddle snippet is `uploadThisFile`, not `uploadFile` ...

Comment: 17 comments; 3 answers; no upvotes yet :(

Answer (score 0):

I have validated, It is working fine.
see here - `jsbin.com/nuzuqomoku/edit?html,js,console,output`

Comment: Please don't answer with a link.

Answer (score 0):

Add a click event through jquery and then call the uploadFile method inside it

```html
<html>
    <head>    
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- HTML -->
        <input id="getFile" type="file" multiple="multiple"/><br />
        <input id="addFileButton" type="button" value="upload"  />
       
        <!-- etc -->
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                function uploadFile(){
                alert('File Uploaded');
            }
                $("#addFileButton").on("click", function() {
                uploadFile();
                console.log("click")
                });
         
           });
         
        </script>
      
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the code:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input id="getFile" type="file" multiple="multiple"/><br />
<input id="addFileButton" type="button" value="upload" onclick="uploadFile();" />
<!-- etc -->
</div>

<script>
  function uploadFile() {
    // code
  }
</script>
```

I don't see a problem with this code. Please make sure that you save and load the right file. You might just forget to load the right file. ^_^